# How to remove the default application for opening a file?

Tags: macos, applications

How do you remove the default open with application for a file extension? Not change it but remove it so when I try to open it a popup says `"There is no application set to open the document “file.blabla”`.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @lhf because sometimes the application associated with the file is changed to something that was not the default system association and you lose the system associated functionality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/). With it, you can set the file association to `<disabled>`
Another option is to use the command line and `lsregister`. `lsregister` is located in `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/` To see all the available commands, run `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister`. See [this article](http://krypted.com/mac-os-x/lsregister-associating-file-types-in-mac-os-x/) for more information.

Comment: I know that, but I want to be able to remove the association, not change it.

Comment: @stas Sorry! Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks but would you happen to know how to do this with the command line? If you don't I'll just use the app.

Comment: @stas Updated again :-)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! I'm just not a big fan of installing tons of apps on my mac, each for doing only a single thing such as the RCDefaultApp.

Comment: No problem. I'm trying to pare down my list too. :-)

Comment: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -u /Applications/Foo.app && killall Finder

Comment: I had an app that wasn't in Applications so to find the path to the .app I used /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -apps local -dump | grep AppName

Comment: The link you provided is dead. For me, I get a timeout.

Comment: RCDefault is no longer available, and probably no longer works.

Answer (score 5):

@Manav proposes in a comment a straightforward and non intrusive way which worked perfectly for me, and I think should be an answer. In a terminal window, run:

/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -u /Applications/Foo.app && killall Finder

Comment: Yes if you want to remove ALL of the associations for an app. But not if you want to choose which extensions to reset that were associated with that app.

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is right click on the file that you want to open, click "get info" (in the dropdown list) then click "Open with"

[image]

After that, select the application you want to open it up with, and select "Change all"

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: This replaces the default file association, not removes.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked.