# Remove Default Application for File Extension in Catalina

Tags: macos

I accidentally associated a file type with an application that doesn't work with that particular file type. (There is no application installed on my system that works with the file.) I would like to remove the default application association. I found this Q&A [How to remove the default application for opening a file?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/47512/how-to-remove-the-default-application-for-opening-a-file) but it seems like it's not exactly what I want and outdated for Catalina. For instance, there is no ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.LaunchServices.plist on my system. I would like to execute a command that removes the association for the one single file extension, not remove all of the associations for an application as this one appears to suggest. I have been able to dump the database using lsregister but I'm not sure what command could be used to remove one entry.

Comment: RCDefaultApp still works on Catalina, according to reports. [Can't test myself, I'm still on Mojave]

Comment: 1) It does not work on Catalina. Or at least my installation of Catalina. Even after unblocking it, System Preferences displays an error when I attempt to use it
2) I would like to understand what commands/file modifications can accomplish this

Answer (score 2):

A Catalina-compatible alternative to RCDefaults can be found here:

https://github.com/Lord-Kamina/SwiftDefaultApps

It provides a preference pane and a command line utility for setting the default app of any file type.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't appear to do what I'm looking for. I installed it via brew but the pref pane doesn't seem to have the ability to associate or disassociate an extension and an app. I scoured the URI Schemes, Uniform Type Identifiers and Applications and none of them have the extension. I know it says it has a CLI but I have no idea where to start and there are no docs.

Comment: @RobbVandaveer Find the UTI of your file type, then select the application options. See the screenshot.

Comment: As I said in my comment, I scoured the URI Schemes, UTIs and Applications and none of them have the extension in question. The extension still has the undesired associated in Finder however.

Comment: @RobbVandaveer What is the file type?

Comment: Nuget Package, extension nupkg. If I dump everything using `lsregister`, I can see an entry for it:
`handlerpref id:     3144 (0xc48)
URL scheme:         nupkg
all roles:          com.aone.keka`

Comment: So `com.aone.keka` is not the list of UTIs?